# The consumption of all the four meat types is

Tags: phrase-request

Let's say there're four types of meat and the consumption of each type is forecast to fall. If I write, "The consumption of all the four meat types is forecast to fall," it might be misleading since readers will think what's going to fall is the total consumption of all four types, not each type's consumption. What should I write to impart my exact idea here?

Comment: Your use of *each* instead of *all* will help.

Comment: If the consumption of each type falls, won't the total consumption of all four types necessarily fall also? Doesn't the first automatically imply the second?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but the second doesn't imply the first, and people might look at my sentence only in the second way, not the first.

Comment: @YosefBaskin So you mean to write "The consumption of each meat type is forecast to fall"? While this sounds to deliver the idea, I somehow feel that it lacks the emphasis we normally give when using "all". Maybe it's just me though.

Comment: @KenAdams If that's the issue, you may be looking for "every": "The consumption of every meat type is forecast to fall."

Comment: Yess, that'd work! I can't believe I didn't think of "every" lol. Thank you both a lot.

Comment: I still say that in this case 'all of the four meat types' and 'each meat type' (knowing there are four) mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Consumption of **all four** meat types is projected to decline.

Not "all *the* four".

The sentence could be paraphrased:
It is projected that each type of meat will be consumed less.

There is no ambiguity.  **all four** would *not* imply  "the *total consumption* involving these four meat types", such that it would be possible that one of them went up and three of them went down.

> All four of them have received a salary increase.

Each employee has received a salary increase.

Comment: If the readers know what **four meat types** I'm talking about, why can't I say **_the_ four meat types**? It's correct to say, for example, **all the students**, isn't it?

Comment: Because "all *the four*" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Hmmm so what's ungrammatical about it? Could you please expand on it?

Comment: Is it because "all" doesn't go with "four", or "the" doesn't go with "four"?

Comment: Do you think "every the four meat types" is grammatical?

Comment: We can say "the four meat types" and "all four meat types" and "all the meat types"  and "all meat types" but not "all the four meat types".

Comment: I didn't think "every the four meat types" is grammatical, but I did think "all the four meat types" is grammatical. From your advice, I came up with a rule for myself, which is never to use three determiners for the same noun. Two is okay, for example, "the four"/
"all the"/"all four", but three is too many.

Comment: We don't use two quantifying determiners together. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order

Comment: But we can say "all *of* the four meat types".